# Getting error in SqlParameter with ParameterName

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am using SqlDataSource1 control in my project.

Source code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CTSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Vehicle" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"  OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="veh_regn_no" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="start_date" Type="DateTime" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="end_date" Type="DateTime" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)
Try
            If (ddlVehicleReg.SelectedIndex > 0) AndAlso (txtStartDate.Text <> "") AndAlso (txtEndDate.Text <> "") Then
                e.Command.Parameters("veh_regn_no").Value = Convert.ToString(ddlVehicleReg.SelectedValue)
                e.Command.Parameters("start_date").Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Nothing)
                e.Command.Parameters("end_date").Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Nothing)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I am getting the error:

> An SqlParameter with ParameterName 'veh_regn_no' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Well what do you expect it to do if the `If` condition is false? Also, you should absolutely *not* be catching and swallowing all exceptions like that.

Comment: Copying from an earlier comment by the OP: "The values is as follows : veh_regn_no = CDT001, start_date= 2/25/2012, end_date = 2/26/2012"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got the answer for the above question.
Use the @ symbol before veh_regn_no
Use like this

```
e.Command.Parameters("@veh_regn_no").Value
e.Command.Parameters("@start_date").Value
e.Command.Parameters("@end_date").Value
```